# Como agrupar resultados mysql por chaves estrangeiras em um único array através de uma única consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Digamos que eu possua 2 tabelas, uma com números de telefone, e outra com setores:

Ex:. 
tb_ramais: id, ramal, grupo_id(fk).

```
id | ramal | grupo_id
01 | 1234  | 01
02 | 2345  | 01
03 | 3456  | 02
04 | 3457  | 02
```

tb_grupos: id, setor, gestor.

```
id | setor   | gestor
01 | setorA | Carlos
02 | setorB | Jose
```

Existe uma forma de obter um array associativo indexado pelo setor?

De forma que todos os dados da tabelas ficassem disponíveis em um único array e através de uma única consulta, sendo possível iterá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
foreach ($resultado['setorA'] as $setorA) {
  // código 
}

foreach ($resultado['setorB'] as $setorB)
  // código
}
```

Atualmente consigo fazer isto através de duas consultas sql, atribuindo uma cláusula `where setor = 'setorX'` para cada uma delas...

Mas eu gostaria de saber se há uma forma de chegar ao mesmo resultado, fazendo apenas uma query e retornando um array associativo indexado pelo setor, e se, isso seria uma boa prática com um número elevado de dados, aonde é necessário considerar, se é interessante o volume de dados em uma única consulta, ou se é mais interessante mesmo, fazer isto em 2 consultas, dividindo os dados em 2 arrays.

A dúvida é ref. a query mysql pura, então não é necessário falar sobre PDO ou outras classes.

Comment: Vou colocar a resposta!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu acredito que assim resolva sua questão de agrupamento, mas, a solução é com [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) e [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'senha';

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    $sts = $pdo->prepare("SELECT b.setor, a.grupo_id, a.id, a.ramal, b.gestor
                         FROM tb_ramais a inner join tb_grupos b on a.grupo_id = b.id
                  ORDER BY b.setor");

    $sts->execute();

    $resultado = $sts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
    print_r($resultado['setorA']); 
    echo '<br>';    
    print_r($resultado['setorB']);
    echo '<br>';
```

---

```
//Setor A
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [grupo_id] => 1
            [id] => 2
            [ramal] => 2345
            [gestor] => Carlos
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [grupo_id] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [ramal] => 1234
            [gestor] => Carlos
        )

)

//Setor B
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [grupo_id] => 2
            [id] => 3
            [ramal] => 3456
            [gestor] => Jose
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [grupo_id] => 2
            [id] => 4
            [ramal] => 4567
            [gestor] => Jose
        )

)
```

---

*`Foreach`*

```
foreach ($resultado['setorA'] as $setorA) {
    print_r($setorA);
    print('<br>');
}
```

---

```
Array
(
    [grupo_id] => 1
    [id] => 2
    [ramal] => 2345
    [gestor] => Carlos
)
Array
(
    [grupo_id] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [ramal] => 1234
    [gestor] => Carlos
)
```

Em relação a desempenho acredito que vai depender de fatores, mas, pode usar isso tranquilamente em seus projetos.

Comment: Apesar de usar PDO, foi o mais próximo do objetivo, agora a pergunta é, tem como fazer isto sem PDO Statement?

Comment: Se você usar mysql_query, não dá! eu não fiz o teste do mysqli para ver se dá, porque, sinceridade eu uso mais PDO acho bem mais prático e com esses recursos ainda ... !!! A final como você conecta e executa SQL 
?

Comment: Eu uso CakePHP, mas é uma questão mais teórica do que prática, vinha pensando nisso hoje, como obter o resultado mais satisfatório, com a menor utilização de recursos e iterações.

Comment: Se eu não me engano o CackePHP deve usar PDO internamente (se alguém souber e se quiser pode dizer o que ele sua) para que todos tenhamos tal conhecimento.

Comment: O Cake aceita statements também, mas era uma dúvida de mysql.
Só fazer algo parecido com isso: `$myPDO = $this->AlgumModel->getDataSource()->getConnection();`

Comment: Legal @MarceloAymone, eu uso Laravel para PHP por isso não sabia!

Comment: É uma faca de dois gumes. Usar dois fetch styles combinados da PDO te permite fazer de forma fácil e rápida (em termos de performance) o que seria possível através de uma lógica mais complexa. Porém, se você não usa a PDO isso te "força" a usá-la (apesar de que deveria usá-la desde "sempre") e, por haver um framework envolvido, você ainda está sujeito à compatibilidade. Hoje é o Cake, amanhã pode ser o ZF ou o Symfony. Mesmo que estes suportem a PDO, de repente você vai precisar mexer num código que não precisaria se tivesse feito à mão.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, desculpa mas, eu não entendi ?

Answer (score 2):

Você já tentou fazer um `JOIN`, nas duas tabelas, exemplo:

```
SELECT
g.setor,
r.ramal,
g.gestor
FROM tb_ramais r
INNER JOIN tb_grupos g
ON r.grupo_id = g.id
```

[Exemplo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b84d3/3)

O resultado desta consulta retorna:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [setor] => setorA
            [ramal] => 1234
            [gestor] => Carlos
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [setor] => setorA
            [ramal] => 2345
            [gestor] => Carlos
        )
...
```

Então você pode fazer:

```
$ramais = array();
foreach ($result as $row){
    $ramais[$row['setor']][] = array('ramal'=>$row['ramal'],'gestor'=>$row['gestor']);
}
```

E você terá o array associativo:

```
Array
(
    [setorA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ramal] => 1234
                    [gestor] => Carlos
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ramal] => 2345
                    [gestor] => Carlos
                )

        )
        ...
```

Então poderá trabalhar o array como:

```
foreach ($ramais['setorA'] as $setorA){
    echo $setorA['ramal'];
}
```

Quanto a viabilidade deta solução, cada caso é um caso, se estamos falando de dezenas, centenas, milhares ou milhões de registros.

Comment: Se eu pudesse reputar duas vezes eu faria. Pela resposta e pela divulgação do SQLFiddle ;)

Comment: Não é esta a pergunta, a questão é como obter um array associativo indexado pela chave estrangeira.

Comment: @MarceloAymone, editei minha resposta, não sei se é isto que esta tentando fazer, mais espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá @abfurlan, agradeço a resposta, mas não, não seria isto.
Neste caso, eu preciso iterar o array para gerar os outros 2, até então tudo ok, poderia fazer desta forma, mas quero saber se há forma de já receber este array sem iterá-lo para gerar outros 2 a serem novamente iterados para listar os resultados.

Comment: Estou chegando a conclusão que não é possível.

Comment: Desconheço uma solução em SQL pura para esta questão.

Comment: Tem sim já to providenciando!!!

Answer (score 1):

Em resposta a [esse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16323/como-agrupar-resultados-mysql-por-chaves-estrangeiras-em-um-unico-array-atraves/16337?noredirect=1#comment30213_16337), em caráter *off-topic*, mesmo que este não seja o modelo do Stack Overflow, porém válido na minha opinião, para que fossem sanadas duvidas sucitadas de um comentário feito de forma mais ampla e completa.

---

1. O PHP é uma linguagem interpretada, tudo aquilo que você faz com ela é por definição mais lento que recursos compilados, nesse caso, a PDO. Sem ela, você precisaria de repente fazer loops aninhados (ruim), lógicas complexas (pior), manipulamento de matrizes (que num loop aninhado, pode ser uma sentença de morte).
2. Se sua aplicação hoje usa MySQL, sempre vai usar MySQL e não existe jeito dela usar outro SGBD por qualquer que seja o motivo, quase sempre não justifica usar a PDO, haja vista que a MySQLi dá e sobra.

   Se você não usa a PDO, usar a solução aqui apresentada apesar de adequado se torna errado pois você está tornando sua Aplicação dependente de um recurso muito grande pra uma tarefa muito pequena, relativamente falando.
3. A questão do framework é um pouco mais delicada.

   Um framework, seja ele *full stack* ou de domínio específico, almejam solucionar todos os problemas do programador por ele (full stack) ou todos os problemas de uma determinada área (domínio específico).

   Seja qual for o caso, solucionar os problemas relativos a acesso de dados requer considerar múltiplos cenários, pois os dados podem vir de qualquer lugar (banco de dados, XML, TXT, WebService...).

   Esqueçamos todos os outros meios e foquemos apenas em bancos de dados. Um framework deve considerar MySQL, PostgreeSQL, SQLite, MSQL dentre outros. E até antes da PDO cada banco de dados era manipulado por uma biblioteca diferente, com uma sintaxe e/ou, principalmente, **uma assinatura** de métodos/funções diferente.

   A PDO veio pra eliminar metade do problema por uniformizar as operações por ela suportadas através uma mesma interface, assim o programador só se preocuparia com a pseudo-linguagem SQL em si, haja vista que elas variam entre SGBDs diferentes.

   Agora sim chego onde queria chegar. O PHP está entrando nos eixos aos poucos, mas por si só, talvez até mesmo pelo excesso de legado que ele carrega até hoje, ele ainda possui assinaturas de método feias, confusas ou mesmo muito verbosas (GD que o diga).

   Enquanto alguns frameworks não se preocupam com isso e permitem que as constantes da PDO sejam usadas normalmente nos métodos respectivos para *fetching* dos resultados, simplesmente direcionando todos os argumentos recebidos para quem de direito - uma das poucas utilidades de [func_get_args()](http://www.php.net/func_get_args) - outros frameworks vão além e tentam por ordem na casa.

   Funciona, claro, mas se você está usando a PDO, teoricamente você está fazendo porque pode vir a precisar de outro SGBD no futuro, mesmo que na prática não seja assim.

   E como eu falei ali em cima existem diferenças entre SGBDs e, de repente, essa técnica pode não estar disponível ou mesmo não estar completamente implementada num banco Informix (seja lá o que ele for) da mesma forma que está para o MySQL.

   Alguns frameworks vão além e tentam, inclusive, contornar esse tipo de problema. Outros, "simplesmente" (porque não é simples mesmo), reescrevem toda a interface da PDO.

   Eu fiz isso no passado, reescrevendo num modelo Orientado a Objetos, renomeando métodos, alterando a ordem dos argumentos, arrumando a bagunça que foi deixada aqui e ali...

   Não vou dizer que o que eu fiz foi certo, errado, melhor ou pior, mas por ser um caso bem, mas bem específico mesmo, a solução apresentada pode não funcionar no meu código porque, talvez, possa carecer de algum recurso que talvez eu tenha deixado passar.