# Select com JOIN retornar um Objeto com Lista Interna

Tags: php, pdo, select

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um select com join onde a tabela segunda tabela irá retornar mais de uma linha e nisso criar um objeto com uma lista interna. Para ficar mais claro veja o exemplo:

```
Tabela Usuario: idUsuario, nome, cpf
Tabela Veiculos: idVeiculo, nome, placa, dono

select: select u.nome, v.placa from Usuario u JOIN Veiculos v ON v.dono = u.idUsuario;

resultado:
joao, kkk-0000
joao, jjj-0000
paulo, iii-9999
paulo, yyy-9999
```

Em PDO eu utilizo o comando PDO::FETCH_CLASS e recebo o seguinte Objeto.

ObjetoConsulta:

```
obj[0] = joao, kkk-0000
obj[1] = joao, jjj-0000
obj[2] = paulo, iii-9999
obj[3] = paulo, yyy-9999
```

Eu gostaria de receber deste seguinte modo:

```
obj[0] = joao, array(kkk-0000,jjj-0000)
obj[1] = paulo, array(iii-9999, yyy-9999)
```

Comment: Talvez [essa resposta ajude](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16337/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você usar:

```
$Ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Vai obter:

```
array(2) {
    ["joao"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "kkk-0000"
            [1]=>
            string(8) "jjj-0000"
        }
    ["paulo"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "iii-9999"
            [1]=>
            string(8) "yyy-9999"
        }
}
```

Não tenho como testar agora, mas talvez com os outros [modos de fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) você também consiga obter um objeto ao invés de um array.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito. Usei do seguinte modo:$Ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);