# Como posso fazer uma select no PHP Com FIREBIRD PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

Eu já fiz uma conexão correta com o Firebird utilizando o PHP, no entanto eu gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer um `select` em um determinado banco. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

```
<?php

$user = "SYSDBA";
$pass = "masterkey";
try{
$lokos=new PDO("firebird:localhost=ja sei 0;dbname=ja sei também",$user,$pass);
 }catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo "Falha na conexão.".$e->getcode();
 }

?>
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68232/usar-pdo-%c3%a9-a-maneira-mais-segura-de-se-conectar-a-um-bd-com-php já da uma ideia de como começar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça desta forma:

```
$user = "SYSDBA";
$pass = "masterkey";
try{
    $lokos=new PDO("firebird:localhost=ja sei 0;dbname=ja sei   também",$user,$pass);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Falha na conexão.".$e->getcode();
}

$stmt = $lokos->prepare("select * from tabela");
$stmt->execute();
$dados = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($dados as $row) {
   echo "{$row->nome_do_campo} <br/>";
}

?>
```

Para mais detalhes, leia a [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).