# Implementar PDO com Prepared Statements

Tags: php

Tenho um código abaixo funcional, porém não consegui entender bem como implementar **Prepared Statements** a este código/Class. Após pesquisa sobre assunto e tentativas, pelo que entendi é simples, alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

```
class Model {
        protected $db;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');
            $this->db->exec("set names utf8");
        }

        public function insert(Array $dados){
            $campos = implode(", ", array_keys($dados));
            $valores = "'".implode("','", array_values($dados))."'";
            return $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `{$this->_tabela}` ({$campos}) VALUES ({$valores})");
        }

        public function read($where = NULL, $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL, $orderby = NULL){
            $where = ($where != NULL ? "WHERE {$where}" : "");
            $limit = ($limit != NULL ? "LIMIT {$limit}" : "");
            $offset = ($offset != NULL ? "OFFSET {$offset}" : "");
            $orderby = ($orderby != NULL ? "ORDER BY {$orderby}" : "");
            $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `{$this->_tabela}` {$where} {$orderby} {$limit} {$offset}");
            $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $q->fetchAll();
        }

        public function update(Array $dados, $where){
            foreach($dados as $ind => $val){
                $campos[] = "{$ind} = '{$val}'";
            }
            $campos = implode(", ", $campos);
            return $this->db->query("UPDATE `{$this->_tabela}` SET {$campos} WHERE {$where}");
        }

        public function delete($where){
            return $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `{$this->_tabela}` WHERE {$where}");            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Olá, esse link é a luz para Prepared Statements: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Qual é a dúvida em especifico? [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91) ajuda em algo?

Comment: rray, ajudou mais um pouco a entender. Parece até que gostaria que fizessem para mim rs, mas na verdade não é. É que após implementação ainda preciso que as funções retornem o mesmo valor no mesmo padrão, do contrário teria que alterar todo o meu controller (MVC). Conseguiria me dar um exemplo de como ficaria após implementação pelo menos a `public function delete($where)`? Acredito que esta seria a luz....

Comment: Só faltou o atributo: `private $tabela;`

Comment: `$conexao = new Model();
$conexao->insert(['campo'=>'valor']);`

Comment: @IvanFerrer as funções, chamadas estão ok. Tudo funcional como sempre esteve, minha dificuldade está sendo em passar estas funções para Prepared Statements, pois até onde entendi em minhas pesquisas, as chamadas são diferentes, e sem falar que onde é retornado por exemplo o fetch associativo não poderá retornar objeto diferente, senão o restante do sistema terá que ser todo mudado. Resumindo preciso manter este script com a mesma essência e resultados mas usando o tal do Prepared Statements. Estou tendo dificuldades e talvez nem explicar estou conseguindo.... agradeço a atenção de vocês...