# Enviar parâmetros via GET

Tags: php, slim

Estou fazendo uma requisição da seguinte maneira.

```
http://localhost/sistema-agenda-server/tarefas/listAll?id=1
```

pedi para ver na resposta o sql gerado e obtive a seguinte resposta:

```
SELECT * FROM tarefas WHERE idu_tar=:id
```

:id não foi alterado para 1.

```
    public function get_listAll($id = null, $filtroData = null, $filtroDuracao = null, $ordem = null)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tarefas WHERE idu_tar=:id ";
        $vars = array(':id' => $id);

        if(!is_null($filtroData))
        {
            $sql .= " AND datf_tar = :filtroData";
            $vars[':filtroData'] = $filtroData;
        }
        if(!is_null($filtroDuracao))
        {
            $sql .= " AND tee_tar = :filtroDuracao";
            $vars[':filtroDuracao'] = $filtroDuracao;
        }
        if(!is_null($ordem))
        {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY :ordem";
            $vars[':ordem'] = $ordem;
        }
        else
        {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY gra_tar";
        }

        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($vars);
        $tarefas = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if($tarefas != null)
            return $tarefas;
        else
            throw new Exception("Erro ao obter tarefas!");
    }
```

Se eu trocar:

`$vars = array(':id' => $id);` para `$vars = array(':id' => $_GET['id'])`;
funciona.
Acredito ser algo simples. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Essa é a rota de acordo com a especificação de controller, action e o o parâmetro , para minhas classes:

```
$app->get('/:controller/:action(/:parameter)',
    function ($controller, $action, $parameter = null) use($app){
        include_once "classes/{$controller}.php";
        $classe = new $controller();
        $retorno = call_user_func_array(array($classe, "get_" . $action), array($parameter));
        echo '{"result":' . json_encode($retorno) . '}';
});
```

Comment: como esta chamado `get_listAll`, pois até aonde entendi deveria ser algo assim: `get_listAll($_GET['id'], ...)`, estou correto? Leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - siga as dicas do link, caso contrário fica difícil ajudar. Tenho certeza que vai entender meu comentário como uma critica construtiva :)

Comment: Mostra ai como vc faz a chamada desse método. o `execute()` não retorna erro?

Comment: $_GET['id'] é o correto mesmo. Se funcionar sem o $_GET é sinal de hospedagem porcamente configurada (ou servidor local apenas para testes, claro), sem os devidos cuidados com a segurança.

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento seria isto que está me perguntando?
    $app->get('/:controller/:action(/:parameter)', function ($controller, $action, $parameter = null) use($app) { include_once "classes/{$controller}.php";
                                                        $classe = new $controller();
                                                        $retorno = call_user_func_array(array($classe, "get_" . $action), array($parameter));
                                                        echo '{"result":' . json_encode($retorno) . '}';
                                                    });

Comment: estou utilizando o framework slim

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque esse códigos dos comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Sua consulta está retornando um erro de sintaxe quando é `$ordem` tem algum valor algo como:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by

Por dois motivos, primeiro `execute()` envia todos os argumentos como string, segundo não é possível fazer um bind com o nome da coluna. Porém existe um hack onde é possível passar o indíce da coluna e tipa-la como int, isso funciona no mysql.

Comment: não entendi muito bem o que disse.

Answer (score 0):

antes do execute do PDO você precisa fazer um bind nos parâmetros, por exemplo abaixo, você está atribuindo um bind direto no seu array, eu nunca vi ser usado desta maneira.

```
//exemplo de bind
$stmt->bindParam("id", $vars['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Abaixo segue o exemplo do insert de uma aplicação controle de tarefas que eu desenvolvi:

```
public function insertTask($dadosTask)
{
  try{
        $query = "INSERT INTO tasks (title_task,description) VALUES (:titulo,:descricao)";
        $query = Database::getInstance()->prepare($query);
        $query->bindParam("titulo", $dadosTask->title_task);
        $query->bindParam("descricao", $dadosTask->description);
        return $query->execute();
     }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

Comment: O bind no `execute()` [funciona](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91). São três tipos, `bindValue()`, `bindParam()` e `execute()`.

Comment: utilizava dessa maneira que me mostrou, mas como eu fiz funciona perfeitamente e acredito que melhora o código pois não precisa chamar a função bindParam varias vezes

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->get('/:controller/:action(/:parameter)', function ($controller, $action, $parameter = null) use($app)
                                                {
                                                    include_once "classes/{$controller}.php";
                                                    $classe = new $controller();
                                                    $retorno = call_user_func_array(array($classe, "get_" . $action), array($parameter));
                                                    echo '{"result":' . json_encode($retorno) . '}';
                                                });
```

Comment: Na pergunta, hehe, esse espaço maior é a resposta. antes da php tem o link editar.

Comment: primeira vez com o stackoverflow,kkkk

Comment: Normal, todo mundo erra, pq está acostumado com o funcionamento de um fórum. Depois da uma olhada nesse [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) ele explica rapidão como funciona o site e pq é diferente de um fórum.

Comment: rray, respondendo sua pergunta lá de cima, chamei o método assim: http://localhost/sistema-agenda-server/tarefas/listAll?id=1 e caiu na minha exception e na exception coloquei a string do sql para ver o que estava indo para a consulta e a a resposta foi SELECT * FROM tarefas WHERE idu_tar=:id...    o placeholder continuou :id

Comment: aaaaah entendi, ta usando rest isso? ta seguindo algum livro/apostila?

Comment: sim, RestFul;......estou seguindo varios livros e sites.

Comment: Já tentou fazer a chamada assim: `http://localhost/sistema-agenda-server/tarefas/listAll/1`. Perguntei do livro pq esse código me lembra [esse](https://github.com/danielschmitz/livro-restful/blob/master/rest-base/index.php)

Comment: rray fiz o index seguindo este livro mesmo. Deu certo utilizando http://localhost/sistema-agenda-server/tarefas/listAll/1 mas como envio os outros parâmetros?

Comment: Preciso modificar minha rota...

Comment: tentei utilizar wildcard route parameters $app->get('/:controller/:action(/:parameter+)' e não consegui... resposta do servidor {'error':{"message":"Array to string conversion"

Comment: Que outro parâmetros?