# Insert Into Não Envia Os Valores

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Eu tenho esse codigo para enviar valores para uma tabela no banco de dados, ela não está exibindo nenhum, simplesmente não está enviando os valores

```
<?php
include "../../lib/inc_con.php";



$mesa = $_POST['mesa'];
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'][0];
$quantidade = $_POST['qtd'];
if(empty($_POST['valor'])) { $adicional = "Nenhum"; } else { $adicional = implode(',', $_POST['valor']);  }
$hiddentotal = $_POST['hiddentotal'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); 
$mysqldata = new DateTime(); 
$data = $mysqldata->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$hora = date('H:i:s');
$produto_id1 = $_POST['produto_id1'];
if (empty($_POST['observacao'])){ $observacao = "Nenhuma"; } else { $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];  }
$produzido = '0';
$valortotal = $quantidade * $hiddentotal;
$asplo = $_POST['asplo'];
$conta = '0';



$pdo=conectar();
$inserirpedido=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pedidos FROM produtos(mesa,tamanho,qtd,adicional,valortotal,data,produto_id1,produzido,observacao,asplo,conta,hora,horadeproducao) VALUES ('$mesa', '$tamanho', '$quantidade', '$adicional', '$valortotal', '$data', '$produto_id1', '$produzido', '$observacao', '$asplo')");
$inserirpedido->execute();

?>
```

Comment: Verifique o erro, `if(!$inserirpedido->execute()){ print_r($inserirpedido->errorInfo());}`

Comment: Tira aquele `FROM` ...

Comment: Tirei o FROM produtos que eu não tinha visto mas continua não inserindo

Comment: e o erro que retornou agora com o errorInfo é que a contagem de colunas não confere com a contagem de valores, vou verificar e volto a fazer contato, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Aquele código do comentário, retornou qual erro?

Comment: Não existem colunas associadas para os 3 últimos valores.

Comment: isso mesmo, eu defini elas só que agora ele ta inserindo 2 registros identicos de uma vez só, sabe o porque isso?

Comment: você chama duas vezes execute?

Comment: Negativo, mas pode deixar que eu vou dar uma olhada aqui, normalmente os erros que dão são falta de atenção minha, obg pela ajuda, qualquer coisa eu crio uma nova pergunta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não adianta nada usar uma API mais nova e mentar os vicios da antiga(mysql_*), não passe os valores diretamente na instrução SQL, passe separados use os placeholders para fazer a associação.

O insert tem dois erros, um from perdido

```
INSERT INTO pedidos FROM produtos
```

Mais colunas que valores especificados.

```
"INSERT INTO pedidos(
mesa,
tamanho,
qtd,
adicional,
valortotal,
data,
produto_id1,
produzido,
observacao,
asplo,
conta,
hora,
horadeproducao) VALUES <---- 13 campos
('$mesa', 
'$tamanho',
'$quantidade',
'$adicional',
'$valortotal',
'$data',
'$produto_id1',
'$produzido',
'$observacao',
'$asplo')"  <--- 10 valores
         <--- e valores para conta, hora e horadeproducao?
```

O código com placesholders fica dessa forma:

```
$inserirpedido = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pedidos FROM produtos(mesa,tamanho,qtd,adicional,valortotal,data,produto_id1,produzido,observacao,asplo,conta,hora,horadeproducao) VALUES (:mesa, :tamanho, :quantidade, :adicional, :valortotal, :data, :produto_id1, :produzido, :observacao, :asplo, :conta, :hora, :horadeproducao)");

$inserirpedido->bindValue(':mesa', $mesa);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':tamanho', $tamanho);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':quantidade', $quantidade);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':adicional', $adicional);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':valortotal', $valortotal);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':data', $data);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':produto_id1', $produto_id1);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':produzido', $produzido);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':observacao', $observacao);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':asplo', $asplo);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':conta', $conta);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':horadeproducao', $horadeproducao);
$inserirpedido->bindValue(':hora', $hora);

$inserirpedido->execute();
```

**Relacionado:**

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)