# Como listar dados específicos de uma tabela com PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como listar dados *específicos* de uma tabela, porem utilizando **PDO**?

Estou começando a estudar e a utilizar **PDO**, porem a algumas coisas que não estou conseguindo encontrar e que esteja bem explicado de como litar os dados com um chamado `WHERE` na busca.

Com o **MySQLi** é utilizado desse jeito, porem como converter para **PDO**??

```
$select     = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `valor1` = '$var_1' AND `valor2` = '$var_2'");
$aRow       = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quti_mh);
$idt        = $aRow['id'];
```

Comment: Não deu para entender, qual é o problema? as vezes não existem registros que satisfaçam o `where` ou ele está errado/invertido/restritivo demais.

Comment: Pelo jeito você não entendeu kkk. Quero saber como listar uma pesquisa especifica em PDO.. @rray

Comment: Acho que [isso ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91), deu a impressão que o problema era na consulta e não quais métodos(`query()`, `prepare()`, `execute()` `fetch*()`) são usados para realizar a consulta.

Comment: A mesma query funciona tanto no PDO quando no mysqli. Acho que a pergunta deveria ser "como fazer uma query no PDO" então. Quanto a usar prepared statements, como foi respondido, isto também é possível (e recomendado na maioria dos casos) em mysqli também. Em resumo, saber fazer o where e saber usar os recursos mais específicos do PDO/mysqli são coisas distintas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Consultas simples

Para fazer um consulta simples com parâmetros fixos ou sem eles pode usar o método [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) ele faz exatamente a mesma coisa que o [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) ou seja processa uma consulta e retorna um resultset que deve ser manipulado para extrair os valores.

O método que retorna as informações do banco de dados é o `fetch*()` ele tem vários [sabores](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), arrays e objetos são os favoritos.

**fetch()**

Quando precisar retornar apenas uma registro(seja para fazer um "alterar/editar") prefira `fetch()` ele retorna um array/objeto na estrutura 'correta' não fazer algo como, `echo $usuario[0]['nome']`, basta apenas `$usuario['nome']`

Estrutura de retorno:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [nome] => Doge
    [senha] => ***
)
```

**fetchAll()**

Para retornar todas as linhas de uma consulta use `fetchAll()` é recomendado em caso onde existem poucos registros.

Estrutura de retorno

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome] => Doge
            [senha] => ***
        )

)
```

**fetchColumn()**

Retorna um escalar (ou seja um valor puro como int, string, float etc ficam de fora dessa lista arrays objetos e outros tipos compostos) de um registros, aceita um argumento que é o indice da coluna da consulta.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste', 'usuario', 'senha');
//* = id, nome e senha
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ativo = 1 limit 300");
$resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($resultado as $item){
    $item['nome'];
}
```

### Consulta com prepared statements

Para evitar problemas com [sql injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91) prepared statements são a solução, pois os valores enviados pelo usuário não são colocados diretamente na instrução sql, para mais detalhes [veja isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91)

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste', 'usuario', 'senha');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?");

if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}

$resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que entendi o que você quis dizer é isso que deseja?

```
$tables = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `valor1` = ? AND `valor2` = ?");

$tables->execute(array('apple', 'green'));
$resultados = $tables->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```