# como fazer uma busca no mysql com php e retornar os dados em cada input?

Tags: php, mysql

meu sistema tem que fazer uma busca, usando o cpf de um paciente, ai quando ele digitar seu cpf, tem que ter uma busca no banco, onde o php vai pegar todas as informações que o paciente tem com aquele cpf que ele digitou (ou seja, ele já possui um cadastro, com nome, cpf, idade, sexo e etc...) e trazer tudo nos inputs corresponderes da pagina html, a mesma pagina que ele usou para se cadastrar, mas vai ser tipo um clone dela.

o código da consulta

```
        <h2>Consultar Ficha do Paciente</h2>

        <div>
            <input class="campo-form" type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14"></br>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <button class="botao" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <a href="php/menuNutricionista.php" class="botoes">Voltar</a>
        </div>

    </form>
```

o codigo php

```
<?php include("conexao.php"); $pdo=conectar(); $cpf = $_POST['cpf']; $consulta= $pdo->prepare("SELECT cpf FROM paciente where cpf = $cpf"); ?>
```

estou com duvidas sobre esse código, provavelmente esta errado e com algumas linhas faltando.
queria que alguem me explicasse como fazer uma estrutura correta de uma query no PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um isset para validar o cpf, adicione um ":cpf" no lugar da variavel cpf na query, o bind é para fazer a segurança da query antes de executar, em seguida execulta e pega o resultado em $resultado, depois no print_r olhe o nome que vem nos index do array, será o nome da coluna por exemplo a coluna do nome do paciente seja nome no $resultado se você fizer echo $resultado['nome'] é para vir o nome do paciente, se não der assim tenten $resultado->nome, depois é só jogar no form, no exemplo joguei o cpf do paciente no form value=cpf; ?>" se não der assim tente  qualquer duvida grita ai no comentário

```
<?php 
include("conexao.php"); 
$pdo=conectar(); 
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
if(isset($cpf)){
$consulta= $pdo->prepare("SELECT cpf FROM paciente where cpf = :cpf");
$consulta->bindParam(":cpf",$cpf);
$consulta->execute();
$resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
print_r($resultado);

}
?>

<h2>Consultar Ficha do Paciente</h2>

        <div>
          <input class="campo-form" type="text" value="<?php echo $resultado->cpf; ?>" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14"></br>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <button class="botao" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <a href="php/menuNutricionista.php" class="botoes">Voltar</a>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: obrigado pela atenção, eu so não consigo entender como vou jogar isso nos inputs. pode parecer uma pergunta idiota e pq não estou conseguindo compreender muito bem. mas eu fiz o que vc me passou e eu vi que ele retornou apenas o cpf.

Comment: fiz mais uma tentativa aqui e agora esa dando o erro: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\teste\consulta.php on line 40 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0012243384{main}( )...\consulta.php:0 "

Comment: no input que deveria aparece a informação, ta aparecendo isso <br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan=

Comment: faça assim @BrunoD.assis ali no print_r($resultado) mostre a saida por favor

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [cpf] => 111.111.111-11 [0] => 111.111.111-11 ) )  e isso que o print_r($resultado) retorna.

Comment: Então @BrunoD.assis por exemplo se você quiser mostrar o cpf dele no campo cpf é só fazer assim olha                                                         
  <div>
        <input class="campo-form" id="cpf" type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" value="<?php echo $resultado[0]['cpf'];?>"><br>
        </div> Se quiser mostrar nome e e-mail e tal tu precisa mudar sua consulta, pois ela só filtra o cpf podes fazer assim a consulta                         "SELECT * FROM paciente where cpf = $cpf"

Comment: entendi, no caso aqui que eu tenho são 39 campos. eu teria que fazer <?php echo $resultado[0]['campo'];?> em cada value e isso? exemplo: <?php echo $resultado[1]['nome'];?>, <?php echo $resultado[2]['email'];?> e etc?

Comment: Sim, teria @BrunoD.assis mas olhe o lado bom, fez uma vez vai ta funcionando sempre

Answer (score 0):

Veja este exemplo, pode ser util, feito em jquery, se quiser só comentar, e tiro suas dúvidas.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
      $(".cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");

      $(document).on("click", ".botao", function () {
        var cpf = $('.cpf').val();
           $.ajax({
              url: 'exemplo.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: 'acao=search&cpf=' + cpf,
              dataType: 'json',
              beforeSend: function () {
              },
              success: function (data) {
                 $("#cpf").val(data[0].user_cpf);
                 $("#nome").val(data[0].user_name);
                 $("#email").val(data[0].user_email);
               },
               error: function (data) {
                  alert('Erro ao solicitar dados');
               }
           });
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Esse é o formulário que você utiliza para enviar os dados

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
        <h2>Consultar Ficha do Paciente</h2>

        <div>
            <input class="campo-form cpf" type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14"><br>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <button class="botao" type="button">Buscar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <a href="php/menuNutricionista.php" class="botoes">Voltar</a>
        </div>

    </form>
```

E esse é o formulário que recebe os dados propriamente solicitado.

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <h2>Consultar Ficha do Paciente</h2>

        <div>
            <input class="campo-form" id="cpf" type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14"><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input class="campo-form" id="nome" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome"><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input class="campo-form" id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
        </div>


        <div class="groupb">
            <a href="php/menuNutricionista.php" class="botoes">Voltar</a>
        </div>

    </form>
```

E aqui é o meu arquivo php que faz a busca.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$acao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'acao', FILTER_DEFAULT);
switch ($acao):
case 'search':
    $array = array();
    $read = new Read;
    $read->ExeRead("ws_users", "where user_cpf = :cpf", "cpf={$_POST['cpf']}");

    if ($read->getResult()):
        $array[] = $read->getResult()[0];
        echo json_encode($array);
    else:
        echo json_encode(array('erro' => 'Erro ao consultar'));
    endif;
    break;
endswitch;
```

Comment: sugiro que você dê ua lida neste tópico, nao custa nada pesquisar!
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111789/como-listar-dados-espec%C3%ADficos-de-uma-tabela-com-pdo