# Concatenar na query PDO

Tags: php, pdo, query, concatenação-de-string

Eu já ouvi falar que ao concatenar em uma `query` usando `PDO` pode causar lentidões e até mesmo deixar o sistema vulnerável, isso é veridico?

Quero concatenar em uma `query` e estou com medo de correr certos riscos.

```
public static function read($table, $where = null) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . self::$_prefix . "{$table}` {$where}";
}
```

Comment: [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91) e [Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizo uma classe para fazer leitura genérica do banco de dados e nunca tive problema de desempenho. O problema maior é que você precisa saber exatamente o que está sendo passado nos parâmetros para fazer a consulta, se não, pode ser realizado sql injection no seu banco de dados, que pode acarretar em problemas.

Criei uma classe em um curso que fiz na internet e desde então utilizo ela para fazer leituras genéricas no banco de dados. Ela é bem completa, faz o tratamento das informações passadas por parâmetro, afim de tentar minimizar o risco de  sql injection. Caso queira utiliza-lá, o funcionamento é bem simples:

index.php

```
    <?php

    include('Config.inc.php');

    // para consultas simples 
    $read = new Read;
    $read->ExeRead('tabela', 'WHERE campo = :valor', 'valor=1');

    if($read->getResult()){

        var_dump($read->getResult());
    } else {

        var_dump($read->getError());

    }

    // para consultas complexas
    $read2 = new Read;
    $read2->FullRead('SELECT tabela.id, tabela2.campo FROM tabela LEFT JOIN tabela2 ON tabela.id = tabela2.id WHERE tabela.id = :id', 'id=1');

    if($read2->getResult()){

        var_dump($read2->getResult());
    } else {

        var_dump($read2->getError());

    }

?>
```

Config.inc.php

```
<?php

// CONFIGRAÇÕES DO BANCO ####################
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'USUARIO');
define('PASS', 'SENHA');
define('DBSA', 'DATABASE');


// AUTO LOAD DE CLASSES ####################
function __autoload($Class) {

    $cDir = array('Conn');
    $iDir = null;

    foreach ($cDir as $dirName):
        if (!$iDir && file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php') && !is_dir(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php')):
            include_once (__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php');
            $iDir = true;
        endif;
    endforeach;

    if (!$iDir):
        trigger_error("Não foi possível incluir {$Class}.class.php", E_USER_ERROR);
        die;
    endif;

}

// TRATAMENTO DE ERROS #####################
//CSS constantes :: Mensagens de Erro
define('AW_ACCEPT', 'accept');
define('AW_INFOR', 'infor');
define('AW_ALERT', 'alert');
define('AW_ERROR', 'error');

//AWErro :: Exibe erros lançados :: Front
function AWErro($ErrMsg, $ErrNo, $ErrDie = null) {

    $CssClass = ($ErrNo == E_USER_NOTICE ? WS_INFOR : ($ErrNo == E_USER_WARNING ? WS_ALERT : ($ErrNo == E_USER_ERROR ? WS_ERROR : $ErrNo)));
    echo "<p class=\"trigger {$CssClass}\">{$ErrMsg}<span class=\"ajax_close\"></span></p>";

    if ($ErrDie):
        die;
    endif;
}

//PHPErro :: personaliza o gatilho do PHP
function PHPErro($ErrNo, $ErrMsg, $ErrFile, $ErrLine) {
    $CssClass = ($ErrNo == E_USER_NOTICE ? WS_INFOR : ($ErrNo == E_USER_WARNING ? WS_ALERT : ($ErrNo == E_USER_ERROR ? WS_ERROR : $ErrNo)));
    echo "<p class=\"trigger {$CssClass}\">";
    echo "<b>Erro na Linha: #{$ErrLine} ::</b> {$ErrMsg}<br>";
    echo "<small>{$ErrFile}</small>";
    echo "<span class=\"ajax_close\"></span></p>";

    if ($ErrNo == E_USER_ERROR):
        die;
    endif;
}

set_error_handler('PHPErro');
?>
```

/Conn/Conn.class.php

```
<?php

    abstract class Conn {

        private static $Host = HOST;
        private static $User = USER;
        private static $Pass = PASS;
        private static $Dbsa = DBSA;

        /** @var PDO */
        private static $Connect = null;

        /**
         * Conecta com o banco de dados com o pattern singleton.
         * Retorna um objeto PDO!
         */
        private static function Conectar() {
            try {
                if (self::$Connect == null):
                    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::$Host . ';dbname=' . self::$Dbsa;
                    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
                    self::$Connect = new PDO($dsn, self::$User, self::$Pass, $options);
                endif;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                PHPErro($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
                die;
            }

            self::$Connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return self::$Connect;
        }

        /** Retorna um objeto PDO Singleton Pattern. */
        protected static function getConn() {
            return self::Conectar();
        }

    }

    ?>
```

/Conn/Read.class.php

```
<?php

class Read extends Conn {

    private $Select;
    private $Places;
    private $Result;

    /** @var PDOStatement */
    private $Read;

    /** @var PDO */
    private $Conn;

    /**
     * <b>Exe Read:</b> Executa uma leitura simplificada com Prepared Statments. Basta informar o nome da tabela,
     * os termos da seleção e uma analize em cadeia (ParseString) para executar.
     * @param STRING $Tabela = Nome da tabela
     * @param STRING $Termos = WHERE | ORDER | LIMIT :limit | OFFSET :offset
     * @param STRING $ParseString = link={$link}&link2={$link2}
     */
    public function ExeRead($Tabela, $Termos = null, $ParseString = null) {
        if (!empty($ParseString)):
            parse_str($ParseString, $this->Places);
        endif;

        $this->Select = "SELECT * FROM {$Tabela} {$Termos}";
        $this->Execute();
    }

    /**
     * <b>Obter resultado:</b> Retorna um array com todos os resultados obtidos. Envelope primário númérico. Para obter
     * um resultado chame o índice getResult()[0]!
     * @return ARRAY $this = Array ResultSet
     */
    public function getResult() {
        return $this->Result;
    }

    /**
     * <b>Contar Registros: </b> Retorna o número de registros encontrados pelo select!
     * @return INT $Var = Quantidade de registros encontrados
     */
    public function getRowCount() {
        return $this->Read->rowCount();
    }

    public function FullRead($Query, $ParseString = null) {
        $this->Select = (string) $Query;
        if (!empty($ParseString)):
            parse_str($ParseString, $this->Places);
        endif;
        $this->Execute();
    }

    /**
     * <b>Full Read:</b> Executa leitura de dados via query que deve ser montada manualmente para possibilitar
     * seleção de multiplas tabelas em uma única query!
     * @param STRING $Query = Query Select Syntax
     * @param STRING $ParseString = link={$link}&link2={$link2}
     */
    public function setPlaces($ParseString) {
        parse_str($ParseString, $this->Places);
        $this->Execute();
    }

    /**
     * ****************************************
     * *********** PRIVATE METHODS ************
     * ****************************************
     */
    //Obtém o PDO e Prepara a query
    private function Connect() {
        $this->Conn = parent::getConn();
        $this->Read = $this->Conn->prepare($this->Select);
        $this->Read->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    //Cria a sintaxe da query para Prepared Statements
    private function getSyntax() {
        if ($this->Places):
            foreach ($this->Places as $Vinculo => $Valor):
                if ($Vinculo == 'limit' || $Vinculo == 'offset'):
                    $Valor = (int) $Valor;
                endif;
                $this->Read->bindValue(":{$Vinculo}", $Valor, ( is_int($Valor) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR));
            endforeach;
        endif;
    }

    //Obtém a Conexão e a Syntax, executa a query!
    private function Execute() {
        $this->Connect();
        try {
            $this->getSyntax();
            $this->Read->execute();
            $this->Result = $this->Read->fetchAll();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->Result = null;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Caso necessitem, tenho também outras classes genéricas que compõe o CRUD para fazer inserção, atualização e remoção de registros do banco de dados.