# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]'

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso gerar uma agenda de um certo periodo, mas está dando esse erro.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(day),data_agenda(month),data_agenda(year)) VALUES('19:00:00','31','12','2016')' at line 1

```
$dataInicio = '2016-01-01';
                $intervalo = 60;

                do {
                    list( $ano, $mes, $dia ) = explode('-', $dataInicio);
                    $inicio = '07:00:00';
                    $final = '19:00:00';
                    do {
                        list($hora, $minuto, $segundo ) = explode(':', $inicio);
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO agenda (hora_agenda,data_agenda(day),data_agenda(month),data_agenda(year)) VALUES('$inicio','$dia','$mes','$ano')";
                        $inicio = date("H:i:s", mktime($hora, $minuto + $intervalo, $segundo, $mes, $dia, $ano));
                    } while ($inicio <= $final);
                    $dataInicio = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia + 1, $ano));
                } while (date('Y') == date('Y', strtotime($dataInicio)));

                $dados = connection::exec($sql);
```

Comment: Não entendo de PHP, Mas colocar o nome das variáveis entre aspas não vai acabar enviando o literal para o banco? Ex.: `'$inicio'` vai mandar o literal **`$inicio`** ao invés do valor da variável.

Comment: Tem algumas coisas fora do lugar, `day()`, `month()` e `year()` são funções para extrair pedaços de uma data, qual o motivo de gravar 3 vezes algum valor na mesma coluna(`data_agenda`) ?

Comment: Você precisa explicar o que quer fazer, para fazer a sintaxe funcionar basta remover `day, month, year`.

Answer (score 1):

`day()`, `month()` e `year()` são funcões para extrair pedaços especificos de uma data e sua chamada no insert está 'invertida' no lugar de `data_agenda(day)` o certo seria `day(data_agenda)`, porem você grava 3 valores diferentes no mesmo campo

O minimo suficiente para funcionar:

```
INSERT INTO agenda (hora_agenda,data_agenda, data_agenda,data_agenda) 
            VALUES('$inicio','$dia','$mes','$ano')
```

Acredito que a sua intenção seja(gravar 3 valores em 3 campos diferentes):

```
INSERT INTO agenda (hora_agenda, dia_agenda, mes_agenda, ano_agenda) 
            VALUES('$inicio','$dia','$mes','$ano')
```

É importante utilizar prepared statements para evitar sql injections e simplificar um pouco a string removendo as aspas simples nos valores.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

Comment: Funcionou dessa maneira, mas só gravou o ultimo registro no banco. Dê um echo na query para ver como o insert está certo.

Comment: @Eduehi o `exec()` que roda o insert está após os dois whiles talvez deveria estar dentro.