# Retornar mensagem de erro para consultas no banco com PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Existe alguma forma de receber mensagens de erro vindas do banco dados ao tentar-se executar uma Query com o PDO do PHP?

Já tentei botar um `try catch` no método `->execute()` mas a classe `PDOException` não captura nada.

Alguém tem ideia de como ser faz?

Comment: Sim é possível! tem algumas maneiras de fazer isso seja com exceptions ou retornos de erros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manipular o error retornando por uma consulta pode-se utilizar exceptions ou retornos de funções(erros).

- Exceptions

O quarto argumento é um array onde algumas configurações podem ser passadas entra elas o `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` e o valor `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` define que os erros serão tratados como exceptions.

Para capturar os erros do banco como exceptions primeiro definia isso no construção do PDO

```
$opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', $opcoes);

$sql = "select ... invalido";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

try{
    $stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

- Retorno de função

A abordagem padrão é essa, verificar o retorno de `execute()` caso seja false use o método `errorInfo()` para obter detalhes sobre o erro, com a mensagem e o SQLState.

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$sql = "select ... invalido";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

if($stmt->execute() === false){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Só tem setar o `PDO::ERRMODE` já bastou para receber as mensagens do banco, OBRIGADO!

Comment: @AdrianoLuz tem outro macetes do PDO nesse link => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91