# O que faz esta instrução ?

Tags: php

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Estou a seguir um tutorial de php que usa esta instrução alguem me pode explicar o que ela faz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retorna uma linha do banco de dados como um array associativo e atribui a `$row`, lembrando que primeiro é executado o `fetch()` e depois a atribuição.

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           2            1        3
```

1 - O método `fetch()` retorna uma linha do banco de dados ou `false` caso não existam mais registros, o que faz o while parar.

2 - É feita a atribuição de `fetch()` em uma variável.

3 - Definição do tipo retornando, nesse caso é um array associativo(chave/valor), pode seria um objeto, array númerico etc, veja os outro tipos na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

[Mais informações sobre o PDO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91)