# Tratar erros de query postgres

Tags: php, pdo

To usando PDO e Postgres, mas to com dificuldade de pegar as exception da query, como por exemplo erro na sintaxe.

Fico grato quem puder dar uma luz!!

Comment: Acho que [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91) responde, caso não poste seu código na pergunta.

Comment: Pode colocar aqui a parte do código que já tem?<br> Ou até mesmo o erro? Ficaria mais fácil de ser analisado

Comment: então, quero implementar o catch e retornar as mensagens de erro que possa haver, como coluna inexistente, erros que não permitam a query executar. Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você quer implementar isso no catch block, primeira coisa é mudar a estratégia de controles de erros do PDO, existem 3 estratégias

- PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT - para obter os erros via errorCode e errorInfo;
- PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING - para emitir WARNING;
- PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION: - para emitir exceções.

Por padrão ele vem com PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT que informa  os erros através de errorCode() e errorInfo(), que seriam pegos dessa forma:

```
try {
   $pdo = new DBClass();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   exit(1);
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABELA';
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
if (!$stmt) {
    list($erro, $erro_driver, $msg_driver) = $pdo->errorInfo();
    switch ($erro) {
       case '42000':
           //ERRO DE SINTAXE SEU TRATAMENTO AQUI... 
           exit(1);
...
}
```

}

errorInfo() retorna um array de três  posições;

1. Código de erro sql state.
2. Segundo o código de erro do driver utilizado.
3. Mensagem de erro emitida pelo driver.

Como no seu caso você quer tratar nas exceções, teremos que mudar a estratégia de controle de erros do PDO da seguinte forma:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

ou seja o mesmo código acima ficaria assim:

```
try {
   $pdo = new DBClass();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   exit(1);
}

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABELA';
try{
   $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
   switch ($e->getCode()) {
       case '42000':
           //ERRO DE SINTAXE SEU TRATAMENTO AQUI... 
           exit(1);
   ...
   }
}
```

)

A classe PDOException ainda possuí os métodos

- getMessage() - Retorna a mensagem da Exceção.
- getFile() - Obtém o nome do arquivo de onde a exceção foi criada.
- getLine() - A linha do erro.
- getTrace() - Retorna o resto da pilha.

Comment: Ótimo Nelson, minha dúvida era pq ele não retornava o getMessage() perfeitamente explicado por ti, vou por em prática aqui no code