# Resultado SQL possui campo e index

Tags: php, sql, pdo, query

Eu possuo uma função em PHP para automatizar as consultas que faço:

```
//arquivo funcao.php
function executaSql($sql, $param=array()){
    try {
        include "config.php";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute($param);
        $response = $q->fetchAll();
        if ( count($response) ) { 
            return $response;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

E então sempre que preciso fazer uma operação com sql eu apenas chamo a função assim:

```
//arquivo consulta.php
$sql = executaSql("SELECT * FROM cadastro_produto");
$sql = executaSql("SELECT * FROM cadastro_categoria");

//e assim por diante
//Os métodos de INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.. São gerenciados por outra função para verificação de erros
```

Porém o resultado que eu obtenho é sempre algo assim:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [nome_categoria] => Painel
        [0] => Painel
        [tipo_categoria] => 3
        [1] => 3
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [nome_categoria] => Chapa
        [0] => Chapa
        [tipo_categoria] => 7
        [1] => 7
    )
)
```

Sempre me retorna um campo `int` com o resultado repetido.

O modo atual que eu utilizo para manipular os dados e me retornar a *array* final desejada é usando a combinação de `foreach` e verificar se o tipo é `int` e, se não, adicionar a uma nova *array*, assim:

```
$data = array();
$i=0;
foreach($sql as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if(!is_int($key)){
            $data[$i][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Após todo esse processo eu obtenho a *array* final:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [nome_categoria] => Painel
        [tipo_categoria] => 3
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [nome_categoria] => Chapa
        [tipo_categoria] => 7
    )
)
```

Então minha dúvida é: Existe algum modo de automatizar esse processo, removendo os resultados da consulta que possuam o tipo `int`, retornando apenas os campos e valores?

Comment: O problema são os indices `0` e `1`? quer eliminar eles?

Comment: @rray isso, pois após o processo eu retorno e uso em JS em JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa duplicação de informação acontece porque nenhum formato de retorno foi definido, `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` é o valor padrão, isso significa que o retorno de `fetch()`/`fetchAll()` será um array onde os índices serão os nomes das colunas e suas posições(que são determinadas no select). Curiosidade: a função `mysqli_fetch_array()` funciona da mesma forma, para evitar disperdícios especifique um formato! :).

**Solução**

Para retornar um array associativo especifique a constante `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, isso pode ser feito([in line](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143141/91)) na chamada de `fetch()`/`fetchAll()` ou forma global direto na conexão, especificando o quarto argumento, que é um array de configurações nesse caso basta especificar uma valor para `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE`.

```
<?php
   $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=catalogo', 'usuario', 'senha', $opcoes);
```

**Relacionado:**

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

[Manual - demais constantes do PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)

Comment: `(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` , não sabia disso

Comment: Excelente opção também! Já possuía outras configurações, como timezone, mas desconhecia esse método para manipulação dos resultados.

Answer (score 5):

Não precisa de fazer o foreach, basta trocar a seguinte linha:

```
$q->fetchAll();
```

Por:

```
$q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Assim define que quer que as linhas sejam retornadas como array.

Para complementar, caso as queira como Objeto:

```
$q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!