# Título variável PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde,
Estou tentando deixar cada página com um título diferente pegando em base o id.
Tenho que adiantar que sou bem iniciante na área e provavelmente não deve ser nada de mais, meu código está assim:

```
<?php
    include 'conta/config.php';

    $codigo = $_GET["id"];
        //echo $id;
        //exit;
    $titulo = "SELECT titulo FROM tbl_criticas WHERE id = $codigo;";

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

        <title>
            <?php echo $titulo; ?>
        </title>
```

No título ele retorna "*SELECT titulo FROM tbl_criticas WHERE id = 34;*".
Mas eu gostaria que retornasse o título do produto 34, alguém me dá uma força aqui ?

Comment: Isso não é o suficiente para extrairo o resultado do banco de dados, ou seja faltou o código de conexão e consulta.

Comment: E como ficaria ?

Comment: Pode ver alguns exemplos, [PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91) ou [MySQLi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/mysqli/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$host    = 'localhost';  
$usuario = 'root';  
$senha   = '';  
$banco   = 'sua_database';  
$porta   = 3306;  
$charset = 'utf8'; // ou pode ser latin1 - depende do charset que vc está usando  

/**  
 * Conecta com o banco de dados  
 */  
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$banco};port={$porta}", $usuario, $senha, array(  
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,  
));  

/**  
 * Configura o charset  
 */  
$pdo->exec("SET NAMES {$charset} COLLATE {$charset}_general_ci");  

/**  
 * Pega o ID via GET e executa a query  
 */  
$codigo = (int)$_GET['id'];  
$stm    = $pdo->query("SELECT titulo FROM tbl_criticas WHERE id = {$codigo};");  

/**  
 * Pega a linha retornada pela consulta  
 */  
$linha = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
?>  

....  
    <title>  
        <?php echo $linha['titulo']; ?>  

        OU ....  
        <?= $linha['titulo']; ?>  
    </title>  
...  

<b>Esse é um script utilizando PDO e conectando ao MYSQL</b>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela solução e pela explicação completa.
Estou muito agradecido, de verdade cara.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'conta/config.php';

$codigo = $_GET["id"];
    //echo $id;
    //exit;
$titulo = "SELECT titulo FROM tbl_criticas WHERE id = $codigo;";
// $connection é a variavel de ligação ao seu banco de dados. que deve estar no seu config.php

$resultado = mysqli_query($connection,$titulo);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado)) {

$titulo_pagina = $row->$seu_campo_titulo_do_banco_de_dados;

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>
        <?php echo $titulo; ?>
    </title>
```

Comment: Deu isso:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mist\critica_conteudo.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mist\critica_conteudo.php on line 11

Answer (score 0):

Opa. Você precisa executar e retornar a consulta.
Pode fazer assim:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT titulo FROM tbl_criticas WHERE id = {$codigo} LIMIT 1");//Executa a query

$titulo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)['titulo'];//Retorna o título
```

Mas o ideal mesmo é que você use algum framework.
Como o [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org) ou [Laravel](http://laravel.com). 
Ou ainda pode ser usado a extensão PDO.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=banco', 'user', 'senha');
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT titulo FROM tbl_criticas WHERE id = {$codigo} LIMIT 1");
$titulo = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['titulo];
```

Comment: Retornou isso na página : 
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mist\critica_conteudo.php on line 10

Comment: As funções `mysql_` foram depreciadas no php5.x e removidas no php7. Não é uma boa ideia recomenda-las.