# Realizar conexão segura no banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, segurança

Me falaram que este modo de conexão não é segura, mas eu não entendi muito bem por quê não é.

```
<?php
$conecta = mysql_connect("HOST", "LOGIN", "SENHA") or print (mysql_error()); 
print "Conexão OK!"; 
mysql_close($conecta); 
?>
```

E qual seria a correção para realizar uma conexão segura?

Comment: Depende do que você chama de conexão segura. Segura em que sentido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque os métodos `mysql_*` foram depreciados na versão 5.5.0 e removidos na versão 7.0.0.

O recomendado é utilizar PDO ou mysqli.

Segue exemplo do uso com o PDO

```
$pdo = PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basededados;charset=utf8", "usuario", "senha");
```

Outra simples usando o Mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user","password","database");
```

Qual você deve escolher ? PDO ou Mysqli ? Veja esse resumo tirado do site [tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Saiba mais sobre os métodos de conexão.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Eu não gosto destas tabelas, pq elas foram feitas para enganar o leitor. "Sentenças preparadas do lado do cliente" é desvantagem. O mysqli tem "Sentenças preparadas do lado do servidor", que é a única forma verdadeira de se fazer isso. Parâmetros nomeados e sentenças preparadas do lado do cliente são concatenações de strings apenas, mascarando a limitação do PDO. Deram uma consertada nisso recentemente, pondo opção do PDO de fazer binding real, mas quase ninguém usa, pq vem desligado.

Comment: Correto. Pensei em retirar a comparação do site oficial. Mas deixei  no link para ele ver. Se bem que dessa tabela, pouca coisa faz sentido, mas dá um caminho para quem não entende. Deixei ainda para que ele pudesse identificar a diferença "não coerente" de ambas. Bem observado.

Comment: É pena que justo esta página o pessoal não traduziu no site oficial. De qq forma, deixei um comentário na pergunta, quem sabe o autor nos explica melhor o que ele chama de "segura". Em termos de "segurança de dados", todas as conexões mencionadas são similares. Nenhuma criptografa ou autentica por padrão. Quanto a segurança no uso das funções, todas permitem sanitização. O problema maior das funções mysql_ são a obsolecência, e nem tanto a segurança. A mysql_ já tinha função de escape, e se o pessoal que não usava, continua não usando (e não usa binding), continua vulnerável com as novas.

Comment: (tem autenticação no sentido de usuário e senha, quis dizer no sentido de assinar a conexão de alguma maneira)

Comment: O fato é que ambas são "seguras" no termo que você citou *Nenhuma criptografa ou autentica por padrão*. Então creio que o real problema esteja na query e não na função em sim.

Answer (score -1):

A forma mais segura pra realizar conexão acredito que seja usando PDO.

Aqui mesmo no StackoverFLow tem uma pergunta similar e a resposta serve para sua indagação.

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68232/usar-pdo-%C3%A9-a-maneira-mais-segura-de-se-conectar-a-um-bd-com-php)