# Problema com select usando php e mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

Sou novo com o desenvolvimento em php e estava vendo alguns exemplos de select em uma tabela no mysql na net, mas sem sucesso de execução.

O código é o seguinte:

```
$conexao = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conexao) or die (mysql_error());  
// CONNECTION ------------------------------------------------------------------


$query = "SELECT * FROM formcontato";
$result = mysql_query($query);    

while($fetch = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo $fetch[0];
}
```

Quando é executado o código, me retorna o erro:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in select.php on line 13

Qual o problema do código acima?

Comment: `mysql_connect` foi considerado descontinuado, use `MySQLi` ou `PDO` para se conectar ao banco.

Deixo um [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/14262) com leitura complementar sobre essas extensões do `php` que gerenciam conexões a um banco de dados.

Comment: Então Marcelo, obg pelo feedback. Sobre o Mysqli aqui deu um erro que era relacionado a ativação dele, como se não tivesse habilitado, mas obrigado vou ler sobre essas 2 formas de conexões.

Comment: Significa que a sua consulta falhou ...

Comment: no seu servidor acesse /phpinfo.php e procure por `mysqli` ou `pdo` elas informam se as extensões estão instaladas no seu servidor, se não estiverem basta instalar