# Validar dados com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, aplicação-web

Estou migrando meu código php no qual estava utlizando sql query para PDO, porém estou encontrando dificuldades em validar dados com este.

OBS:Já possuo um arquivo funcional que faz a busca no banco de dados, minha dificuldade está realmente em compara-la com o POST e valida-las.

OBS2: Se alguém puder me passar algum link para ajudar na migração do mysql_ para PDO ajudaria demais!

**Segue o código php no qual estou tentando fazer funcionar:**

```
if(isset($_POST['entrar']) && $_POST['entrar'] == "login"){
    $ID = $_POST['usuario'];
    $senha = $_POST ['senha'];
    if (empty($ID) || empty ($senha)){
        echo '<p style="font: 20px Verdana; position:absolute; top:700px; left:40%; color:red;">Por favor preencha os campos!</p>';
    }
    else{
        $buscar=$pdo->prepare("SELECT ID, senha, usuario FROM usuarios WHERE ID='$ID' AND senha='$senha'");
        $buscar->execute();
        $linha=$buscar->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($linha as $listar){
        if ($listar >0){
            $_SESSION['ID'] = $busca ['ID'];
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $busca ['usuario'];
            header ('location:logado.php');
            exit;
        }
        else{
            echo '<p style="font: 30px Verdana;  text-align:center; color:red;">Usuario ou senha invalidos.';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=index.html" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? quando for fazer testes pode comentar os `header()` do código para ver as mensgens de erro.

Comment: `$listar` vem de onde?

Comment: Erro meu, corrigido. O problema está no if provavelmente, não estou sabendo como compara-lo para fazer essa validação com sucesso, mudei apenas um pouco em comparação com o código utilizando sql_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quem tem o resultada da consulta `$linha` e não `$busca`. Se vai retornar apenas um registro use `fetch()` no lugar de `fecthAll()` isso elimina um foreach desnecessário.

```
if(!empty($_POST['entrar']) && $_POST['entrar'] == "login"){
    if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty ($_POST['senha'])){
        echo '<p style="font: 20px Verdana; position:absolute; top:700px; left:40%; color:red;">Por favor preencha os campos!</p>';
    }else{
        $buscar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ID, senha, usuario FROM usuarios WHERE ID = ? AND senha = ?");
        $buscar->execute(array($_POST['usuario'], $_POST ['senha']));
        $linha = $buscar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($buscar->rowCount()){
            $_SESSION['ID'] = $linha['ID'];
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $linha['usuario'];
            header ('location:logado.php');
            exit;
        }else{
             echo '<p style="font: 30px Verdana;  text-align:center; color:red;">Usuario ou senha invalidos.';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=index.html" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, havia pensado no foreach como uma forma de comparar todos um de cada vez. Obrigado!

Comment: @Wel se tiver interesse sobre como trabalhar com o PDO veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91)