# Por que o erro em PDO Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch()?

Tags: php, pdo

Não sei porque desse erro.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myschool.com.br/login.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myschool.com.br/login.php on line 24

PHP

```
use dao\Connection;

session_start();
//Incluir a conexão com banco de dados
include 'application/dao/Connection.php';
date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT+3");

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $res='';
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT idlog, logname 
            FROM login 
            WHERE logemail='$email' AND logpassword=md5('$senha')
                AND logBlocked = 'no' AND logstatus = 1;";
    $res = Connection::getInstance();
    $res->prepare($sql);
    $res->exec($sql);

    $dados = $res->fetch();


    if(empty($dados)){
        echo "<script>alert('Seu login falhou. LOGIN: admin@admin.com SENHA: 123');</script>";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $dados['id'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $dados['name'];
        header("location: index.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: Você não passou `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
`

Comment: Acho que o problema está no prepare, os parâmetros de fetch são opcionais, armazene `$res->prepare($sql)`; em uma variável e instancie exec com ela

Comment: troque `exec` por `execute`

Comment: Rafael Augusto  fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); foi a primeira coisa que tentei e não funcionou.

Comment: Everton  deu  ao usar execute  -   Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute().  Eu acho que o erro ta depois do exec  ...

Comment: E `Connection::getInstance` retorna uma instancia de PDO?

Comment: sim isso ta funcionando, é uma instancia de singleton. Mas isso ta funcionando, até porque deu um trabalho grande descobrir como funcionava.

Comment: O erro se dá sempre na linha 24 que é a linha do fetch. Isso quer dizer que a pesquisa funciona e a conecção com o banco tambem funciona, ate porque tinha errado onome de um campo e ouve um aviso de nome de campo errado. Então conecto com o banco faço o select mas na hora de colocar dentro de uma variavel da pau..

Comment: Felipe Duarte tambem não funcionanou fiz $variavel = $res->prepare($sql);   $dados= $variavel->fecth(); e da erro em exec.  Tentei isso agora  ->>>   $res->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->exec($res);
    $dados = $stmt->fetch(); deu o erro Call to a member function exec() on array

Comment: Ah e declarei as variaveis dados e stmt como sendo array, não sei se é certo mas o comando não funciona se não for declarado as variaveis, da unknow variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código não funciona porque nenhum PDOStatement é processado. `prepare()` retorna um, logo é necessário atribuir em um variável. Para enviar a consulta para o para é obrigtário a chamada de `execute()` e por último chamar o `fetch()/fetchAll()`

mude:

```
$res->prepare($sql);
$res->exec($sql);
```

Por:

```
$sql = "SELECT idlog, logname FROM login
        WHERE logemail= ? AND logpassword=md5(?)
        AND logBlocked = 'no' AND logstatus = 1;";

$stmt = $res->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt->execute(array($email, $senha))){
   echo '<pre> erro: ';
   print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
   exit;
}
$dados = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Apos fazer o que o rray sugerio.   Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myschool.com.br/login.php on line 24
 erro: Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)

Comment: @FabianodeSouzaPereira corrigi a resposta, veja que mudei a SQL e o `execute()`.

Comment: 100% rray. Muito obrigado. Cara que comando difícil. Ou eu entendo pouco de PHP . eh eh.

Comment: @FabianodeSouzaPereira `exec()` e `execute()` confunde as vezes :). Se tiver interesse em como utilizar melhor o  PDO [veja essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91)