# Conversão para PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para transformar o seguinte código para PHP PDO.

Fiz as seguintes conversões e comentei a frente do código, apenas pera sanar a dúvida mesmo. Será se a conversão esta correta?

```
<?php

function retorna($cod_material, $conn){
  $result_aluno = "SELECT nome FROM lista_geral WHERE cod_material = '$cod_material' LIMIT 1";
  $resultado_aluno = mysqli_query($conn, $result_aluno);
//$resultado_aluno = $pdo->query($conn, $result_aluno); //CONVERTIDO

  if($resultado_aluno->num_rows){
    $row_aluno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_aluno);
   //$row_aluno = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC($resultado_aluno); //CONVERTIDO
    $valores['nome'] = $row_aluno['nome'];
  }else{
    $valores['nome_aluno'] = 'Aluno não encontrado';
  }
  return json_encode($valores);
}

if(isset($_GET['cod_material'])){
  echo retorna($_GET['cod_material'], $conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Aqui e para sanar dúvidas e não fazer códigos para você, estude a respeito de PDO, veja vídeos, leia livros e apostilas e irá conseguir, com esforço e dedicação

Comment: Voce esta demonstrando que copiou e colou este código aqui, quem sabe programar em php facilmente entende o pdo me desculpe, mas vou tentar lhe ajudar sim

Comment: Esse código aí está errado, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91) tem como converter do `mysql_` para o PDO.

Answer (score -2):

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class Database
{
    private static ?PDO $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function getInstance(): PDO
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase';
            $username = 'myusername';
            $password = 'mypassword';
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            ];
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

// Exemplo de uso
$db = Database::getInstance();
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(['id' => 1]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo $row['name'];
```

Neste exemplo, a classe Database implementa o padrão Singleton, garantindo que apenas uma instância de PDO seja criada e reutilizada em todo o código. A conexão é estabelecida no método getInstance() e as credenciais e opções são definidas no próprio método.

Observe também o uso de tipagem forte no código, com a declaração de tipos de retorno para o método getInstance() e outras variáveis, como $instance e $options. Isso ajuda a garantir que os tipos de dados usados no código sejam consistentes e reduz erros de tipo em tempo de execução.

Segue abaixo o código convertido para usar PDO com padrão Singleton:

```
<?php

function retorna($cod_material, $pdo){
  $result_aluno = "SELECT nome FROM lista_geral WHERE cod_material = :cod_material LIMIT 1";
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($result_aluno);
  $statement->execute(array(':cod_material' => $cod_material));

  if($statement->rowCount()){
    $row_aluno = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//PDO::FETCH_ASSOC é opicional já que defimos PDO::FETCH_ASSOC como padrão na class Database
    $valores['nome'] = $row_aluno['nome'];
  }else{
    $valores['nome_aluno'] = 'Aluno não encontrado';
  }
  return json_encode($valores);
}

if(isset($_GET['cod_material'])){
  $pdo = Database::getInstance();
  echo retorna($_GET['cod_material'], $pdo);
}
?>
```

Note que o método retorna() agora recebe o objeto PDO ao invés da conexão mysqli. Além disso, a query agora usa placeholders com bind de valores na execução, evitando possíveis vulnerabilidades de SQL Injection. Para recuperar os resultados, usamos o método fetch() com o modo de busca PDO::FETCH_ASSOC. Finalmente, a conexão PDO é obtida através da classe Database usando o padrão Singleton, que garante que apenas uma instância da conexão seja criada e compartilhada entre todas as requisições.