# PHP erro ao gravar usando aspas

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando gravar um registro em um banco MySql, porém, o mesmo dá erro pois um dos campos recebe o valor `Frantchelle's` com aspas.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'S BURGUER'S', idCategoria = '1', subcategoria = 'HAMBURGUERIA', descricao = '', ' at line 1update empresas set nome = 'FRANTCHELLE'S BURGUER'S', idCategoria = '1', subcategoria = 'HAMBURGUERIA', descricao = '', endereco = 'RUA PEDRO CâNDIDO DA SILVA, 174 ', bairro = 'GLORIA', latitude = '-8.616116900000000', longitude = '-35.948267400000000', cor = '#000000', wifi = '0', cartao = '0', delivery = '1', uf = '26', municipio = 'CUPIRA', horario = 'SEG. à SáB. POR ENCOMENDA. ' where id = '49'' in C:\wamp\www\buscafree\atualiza.php on line 86

Comment: Não usa prepared statements?

Comment: @rray não uso. alguma dica?

Comment: Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3869/91) ou se utiliza o PDO [essa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91). É quase certeza que esse apóstrofo que vem da do valor fecha a aspa simples e o que deveria fechar acaba por abir outra string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a função `addslashes` do `PHP` nessa `string`, exemplo:

```
addslashes("Frantchelle's"); //Frantchelle\'s
```

`\`(Barra invertida) no `MySQL` é o caractere de escape, por isso ele não irá tratar esse `'` como fechamento da `string`.

Veja mais sobre addslashes [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php).