# Dados retornados em um array estão duplicados

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

Estou executando um SELECT no banco através de uma função e retornando o resultado como um array multidimensional, onde cada índice primário refere-se a um registro, e os índices secundários são os campos do banco com os valores.

Abaixo está a montagem do retorno da função:

```
$resultado = $this->conn->query($sql);
if ($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
   foreach($resultado as $chave => $valor){
      $retorno[$chave] = $valor;
   }
   return $retorno;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Quando pego o retorno e executo um `var_dump()`, o resultado sai assim:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'usu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'usu_nome' => string 'Administrador' (length=13)
      1 => string 'Administrador' (length=13)
```

A segunda dimensão do array está criando dois índices para o retorno: "0" e "usu_id", assim como "1" e "usu_nome".

Isso está correto? O PHP age assim mesmo ou há um erro na maneira como estou montando o array de retorno?

Comment: Não está duplicado, na hora de fazer o Fetch é necessário informar o tipo de resultado. Você está usando PDO, Mysqli ou o que para conectar com a base de dados?

Comment: No PDO eu uso $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);, onde somente retorna por atributos por chave

Comment: pq precisa do foreach?

Comment: @Sveen - estou usando PDO com banco MySQL.

Comment: @rray - A minha ideia é montar um array com o retorno do banco e retornar esse array, ao invés de retornar o objeto de retorno (PDOStatement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por padrão o retorno de consultas do PDO é o [PDO::FETCH_BOTH](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) que devolve os dados duplicados sendo um índice com o nome do campo e outro índice númerico.

Pode definir o formato dos dados de três formas:

No construtor que afeta todas as consultas feita por essa conexão.

```
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pdo = new PDO('.....', $options);
```

No método `query()` apenas a consulta atual é afetada.

```
$result = $pdo->query('select ....', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

E por último na extração no método `fetch()`/`fetchAll()` onde o formato é passado como argumento.

```
 $result = $pdo->query('select ....');
 $info = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach($info as $item){
    echo $item['chave'] .'<br>';
 }
```

Como só retorna os dados sem nenhuma manipulação pode dar o `return` direto em `query()` ou no `fetch()` caso deseje adicionar tratamento a erros.

```
$resultado = $this->conn->query($sql);
if ($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
    return $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
   return $this->conn->errorInfo();
}
```

Comment: Cara, ajustei a chamada da query conforme você sugeriu e resolveu na hora! Coloquei <code>$resultado = $this->conn->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);</code> e ele trouxe o array de retorno sem os índices pelos números, apenas pelos nomes das colunas da tabela, como eu queria. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @RodrigoTognin tem mais uns macetes do PDO [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91) caso tenha interesse.