# Conversão MySql Para PDO

Tags: php, mysql, query, pdo

```
@$sql_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuario ";
@$qry_usuario  = @mysql_query($sql_usuario );
@$linha_usuario  = mysql_fetch_array($qry_usuario );
```

Array ( [0] => 6 [u_id] => 6 [1] => 54354554[u_cod] => 54354554[2] => 54354554[u_cod] => 54354554) Array ( [0] => 17 [u_id] => 17 [1] => 3232323[u_cod2] => 3232323[2] => 3232323[u_cod2] => 3232323)

Tenho essa `query`. Como eu converteria para `PDO`? O retorno dos dados são diferentes:

```
@$sql_usuario  = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario");
@$sql_usuario->execute();
@$linha_usuario = $sql_usuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Array ( [u_id] => 6 [u_cod] => 54354554[u_cod] => 54354554) Array ( [u_id] => 17 [u_cod2] => 3232323[u_cod2] => 3232323)

Comment: Não entendi esse `@` no começo das variáveis. Postei na resposta um exemplo extremamente simples, que irá auxiliá-lo na questão. Caso tiver dúvida, pergunte.

Comment: [Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

Comment: O @ é pra não dar erro de index vazio

Comment: A saida dos dados no caso os fetchs são diferentes entende, gostaria de que elas seguissem um padrão

Comment: @Aprendiz Sim, mas não tem motivo de "ocultar" o erro, pois é um "erro", deve ser tratado.  Quando ao "padrão" de "fetchs" não entendi. Edite sua pergunta, detalhe melhor, exemplifique.

Answer (score 0):

Tente em PDO o seguinte:

@$sql_usuario  = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario");
@$sql_usuario->execute();
@$rows = $sql_usuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Answer (score 0):

Vou postar um exemplo bem simples, que irá conseguir facilmente converter, de forma que aprenda cada detalhe:

Arquivo: `config.php`

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$user = 'root'; # Usuário do banco de dados
$pswd = '123';  # Senha

# Tentativa de conexão
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.0.1; dbname=nomedobanco', $user, $pswd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Arquivo: `login.php`

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
require_once('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();

# Verifica se tem ao menos 1 linha
if($statement->rowCount()) {

    # Imprimindo o retorno
    $stt = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($stt);

} else {

   echo "Sem dados.";
}
```